# RecyclerViewAdapter to New Fragment Transaction

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have written in Code Section

Main Activity, In Main Activity, there are 3 Fragments, fragments 1, 2 & 3.

In the fragments 1, I'm showing a Text and some Images from an URL by Using a `RecyclerView` adapter. The total number of Texts and Images is 27 items. It means `item1(text1, image1)`, `item2(text2, image2)` ...  `itemN(textN, imageN)`

So I want to set an `OnClickListener` that works for

```
//this is pseudo-code
if (text1 is clicked) 
{
    goto NEW FRAGMENT1;
}
if (text2 is clicked)
{
    goto NEW FRAGMENT2;
}
```

So let's talk about the code, in my `RecyclerView` I'm Successfully able to identify which item is clicked. My only problem is, I was unable to transfer from `RecyclerView` to new `Fragment`. In the `getSupportFragmentManager` or `getFragmentManager` I'm getting an error.

A Sample Code of my code:

```
viewHolder.item_shows.setOnClickListner(new View.OnCliclListner(){
@Override
public void onClick (View view)
{
String itemPosition = String.valueOf(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
// item position works fine. Its shows which number item clicked.
// ******** HELP **********}}};
return viewHolder;
--------------------
//In ******** HELP ********** this position I want to create
if(iemPosition.equals("0"))
{open New Fragment1}
if(itemPosition.equals("1"))
{open New Fragment2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass reference of your activity in constructor of adapter. 
Because `getSupportFragmentManager()`  is method of activity class not your adapter class.

```
class MyAdapter(Activity mActivity,ArrayList<Model> list){

}
```

so use it like below to replace fragment in your activity container.

```
mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: How can I pass Activity ? 

My Adapter Code is

Comment: i told you to pass in constructor of adapter. see in my answer

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Sd8plw70tOmK8TWFX3D6lcs-nWorOnaDwzlY63cnUiw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: change in your adapter constructor  make context to activity and you can use activity.getSupportedFragmentManager()  in on Click Below is code 


`public RVHS(Activity activity, List<SH> SHs) {
       this.activity = activity;
       this.SHs = SHs;
   }`